# C++ Check if a Queue is FULL?

Tags: c++, queue

```
void enqueue(int val){ 
if (Queue is full, do this){ 
//... What should I write here?  ...

}else{ 
if(empty()){ 
   r = f = 0; 
}else{ 
   r++; 
   int arr_length = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])) - 1; 
if(r == arr_length) 
   r = 0; 
} 
   arr[r] = val; 
} 
}
```

My Question: there will be 2 pointers in a Queue. Pointer R that points to the REAR of the queue. Pointer F that points to the FRONT of the queue. When deleting an element from the Queue, the first element in the queue will be removed, hence, F = F-1; And when adding a new element into the Queue, it will be added to the last position in the queue, hence R = R+1.

Let's say I declare a fixed array size of 5. R and F can warp around in the Queue (circular array). How do I check if the Queue is full?

**What I have thought of to check if the Queue is full:**

> Case 1 - When F is pointing at array first element & R is pointing at
>   array last element = Queue is full.
>
> Case 2: When F - 1 = R. Then Queue is full.

Is my logic correct? How to implement in coding?

Comment: Rather than re-inventing the wheel you could just use [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

Comment: I'm afraid your question is rather unclear as it is. Are you asking how to represent a queue in memory? Or do you have this sorted out (then add the info to the question) and you're asking about implementing a particular operation over that representation?

Comment: @PaulR Depends on whether the goal is to "have a queue" or "learn to program data structures."

Comment: I think you are using only one `=` to instead of `==`

Comment: @Agnew: yes, I couldn't tell from the question whether this was a homework assignment or an actual project. The question quality seems a little too high to be the usual homework type of question so I thought the OP might actually be misguidedly trying to implement a queue from scratch.

Comment: @PaulR Can `std::queue` use a `std::array` as it's underlying container? Since the OP seems to ask for a _fixed size_ queue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yes, so long as the underlying container meets the requirements of a SequenceContainer, which is true for various containers, including `std::array` (from C++11 onwards): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer

Answer (score 0):

Your Queue isFull check is ok for:

```
Case 1 - When F is pointing at array first element & R is pointing at array last element = Queue is full.

Case 2: When F - 1 = R. Then Queue is full.
```

When full, you cannot do enqueue
So, better would be to return as book, if you cannot enqueue (when full), return false, and true otherwise i.e. if could enqueue.
This will help your caller that calls enqueue or dequeue

Alternately you may use std::queue or std::array